# SwiftUI text-alignment

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Among the many properties of the `Text` view, I couldn't find any related to text alignment. I've seen in a demo that it automatically handles RTL, and when placing stuff using View's `body`, it always centers it automatically.

Is there some concept that I'm missing about layout system in `SwiftUI` and if not, how can I set the text alignment properties to the `Text`?

Answer (score 550, accepted):

You can do this via the modifier `.multilineTextAlignment(.center)`.

```
Text("CENTER")
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/multilinetextalignment(_:))

Comment: Is something exists to justify text ?

Comment: These seems to only work if the text is long enough to wrap.  So this example does not work?

Comment: @Christopher: if the text is not long enough to wrap and you did not fill the parent view, it will take the space it needs to display the text, and thus center in a space exactly the same size, which does nothing. Try adding a border to your Text to see what I mean.

Comment: See StaticVoidMans answer below.

Answer (score 367):

From SwiftUI beta 3 forward, you can center a text view with the frame modifier:

```
Text("Centered")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
```

Comment: For some reason, ".multilineTextAlignment()" wasn't giving me the results I wanted, but this did.

Comment: This doesn't work for the majority of case

Comment: The reason this one works is because if it's a tight square, having it aligned to its leading, center or trailing is the same since it's just squished in there, but the frame expands that square, so then the alignment makes more sense

Answer (score 245):

Was trying to understand this myself as other answers here mention `Text.multilineTextAlignment(_:)` / `VStack(alignment:)` / `frame(width:alignment:)` but each solution solves a specific problem. Eventually it depends on the UI requirement and a combination of these.

---

#### `VStack(alignment:)`

The `alignment` here is for the inner views in respective to one another.
So specifying `.leading` would associate all inner views to have their leading aligned with one another.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
  Text("Lorem ipsum dolor")
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
  Text("sit amet")
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
}
.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
```

[image]

---

#### `.frame`

In `frame(width:alignment:)` or `frame(maxWidth:alignment:)`, the `alignment` is for the contents within the given width.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
  Text("Lorem ipsum dolor")
      .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
  Text("sit amet")
      .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
}
.frame(width: 380, alignment: .trailing)
.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
```

The inners views are leading aligned respective to one another but the views themselves are trailing aligned respective to the `VStack`.

[image]

---

### `.multilineTextAlignment`

This specifies the alignment of the text inside and can be seen best when there are multiple lines otherwise without a defined `frame(width:alignment)`, the width is automatically adjusted and gets affected by the default `alignment`s.

```
VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 6) {
  Text("0. automatic frame\n+ view at parent's specified alignment\n+ multilineTA not set by default at leading")
    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
  Text("1. automatic frame\n+ view at parent's specified alignment\n+ multilineTA set to center")
  .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
  .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
  Text("2. automatic frame\n+ view at parent's specified alignment\n+ multilineTA set to trailing")
  .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
  .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
}
.frame(width: 380, alignment: .trailing)
.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
```

[image]

---

#### Tests with combinations:

```
VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 6) {
  Text("1. automatic frame, at parent's alignment")
  .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
  Text("2. given full width & leading alignment\n+ multilineTA at default leading")
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
  .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
  Text("3. given full width & center alignment\n+ multilineTA at default leading")
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
  .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
  Text("4. given full width & center alignment\n+ multilineTA set to center")
  .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
  .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
  Text("5. given full width & center alignment\n+ multilineTA set to trailing")
  .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
  .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
  Text("6. given full width but no alignment\n+ multilineTA at default leading\n+ leading is based on content, looks odd sometimes as seen here")
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
  .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
}
.frame(width: 380)
.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very compelling answer. Thank you. I will consider making this an accepted answer as well.

Comment: @inokey glad to share my observations :) I later found an interesting article going more in depth with view alignments in general: [Alignment Guides in SwiftUI](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides)

Comment: awesome stuff man. SwiftUI really evolved since I originally posted that question.

Comment: Do you know why multi line tex becomes one line if I put ex. `Spacer().frame(height: 50)` If I remove the height from the spacer, the multi line text shows all lines. How do I force showing all lines?

Comment: I hate it that this is not the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 34):

I've actually run into the problem where I had to align text on a single line. What I've found to work is this:

```
Text("some text")
    .frame(alignment: .leading)
```

If you combine this with the frame width parameter you can get some nice text block formatting for labels and such.

Answer (score 30):

I guess `SwiftUI` wants us to use wrappers like stacks for such things.

So instead of writing something like `Text("Hello World").aligned(.leading)`, the following is encouraged:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Hello World")
}
```

Comment: So I can't just drop a label that is independent of stack?

Comment: @inokey I didn't find a modifier for this at least.

Comment: I didn't either. It seems to me like I miss some sort of a base concept from SUI. I can't even drop like just the "view" in between two things, and give it a color, like they don't have plain a-la-uiview object in there.

Comment: The frame modifier has an alignment parameter

Comment: Seems silly to have to do (although it does work). Where did you hear that this was encouraged?

Answer (score 21):

We need to align the Text and not the Stack it's in. So calling `multilineTextAlignment(.center)` and setting the line limits I can be able to see the texts aligned to center. I don't know why I have to set the line limits, I thought  it would expand if you have a large text.

```
Text("blahblah")
        .font(.headline)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .lineLimit(50)
```

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem.
i used this for fixing that.

```
Text("Test")
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
```

Comment: This produces very strange results, I wouldn't recommend

Comment: This resolved my problem. I tried to implement GridItem(s) and inside it Circle() and Text() is there. But Alignment of text makes my UI messy. After trying 2 hours this answer saved my! JazakAllah Khair Kaseera.

Answer (score 18):

If you would like to keep constant width for the Text, the ".multilineTextAlignment(.leading)" won't take any effect until there is only one line of text.

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
struct LeftAligned: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack {
            content
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}


extension View {
    func leftAligned() -> some View {
        return self.modifier(LeftAligned())
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Text("Hello").leftAligned().frame(width: 300)
```

Answer (score 17):

There are multiple ways for the alignment of text in SwiftUI-

1st-

> ```
> VStack(alignment: .leading){    
>    Text("Leading alignment")    
> }
> ```

2nd -

> ```
> VStack{    
>    Text("Leading alignment")
>      .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)    
> }
> ```

3rd -

> ```
> VStack{    
>    Text("Leading alignment")    
> }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
> ```

And to shift the whole block of text use **Spacer()** under the HStack -

> ```
>  HStack {  
>     Text("Leading alignment")   
>     Spacer()  
>  }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, particularly the 3rd option; it's very simple. 

For anyone looking to centre-align: wrap the `Text()` blocks with a `Spacer()` on top and below, inside of the `HStack{}`. For right-alignment, simply put a `Spacer()` on top of the `Text()`.

Answer (score 14):

You can set alignment for Vertical stackView as leading. Like below

```
 VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Turtle Rock")
                .font(.title)
            Text("Joshua Tree National Park")
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I'd like to use `Spacer()` view to aligning text block.
This example show text at the trailing side:

```
HStack{
    Spacer()
    Text("Wishlist")
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can always add a frame to the Text field and can modify it's alignment.

```
Text("Hello World!")
   .frame(alignment : .topLeading)
```

Since, this is just for a couple of lines - this is better than using alignment on either of the Stacks

Answer (score 3):

#### Default `.center` value

You can redefine `multilineTextAlignment()` method using a modified content:

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func multilineTextAlignment() -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: AlignedText())
    }
}

struct AlignedText : ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(.black)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
}
```

...and then use `multilineTextAlignment()` with no explicit parameter's value.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("SwiftUI SwiftUI SwiftUI SwiftUI SwiftUI")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .multilineTextAlignment()    // Center alignment is a new DEFAULT
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but I have experienced that SwiftUI automatically switches to RTL for languages like Arabic, you don't need to explicitly specify that like in UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property of SwiftUI

> [**multilineTextAlignment**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/multilinetextalignment(_:))

for TextAlignment.

```
VStack { 
    Text("Your Text")
      .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
}
```