# Display Text in left of view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i have one screen on my app witch gets data from firebase and then displays it. But i want to have 2 Text() view the one below the other, but for some reason the text is not displaying in the left of the view

**The problem:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
struct ResourceItem: View {
    
    var title: String
    var url: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Link(destination: URL(string: url)!) {
                
                Text(title)
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                
                Text(url)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI text-alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443535/swiftui-text-alignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Link` creates it's own `VStack` with default configuration. That's why when you place `Link` inside `VStack` - outer container is ignored.

You need to place `VStack(alignment: .leading)` inside `Link`:

```
struct ResourceItem: View {
    
    var title: String
    var url: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Link(destination: URL(string: url)!) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(title)
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                Text(url)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
VStack (alignment: .leading) {
    Text(title)
        .bold()
        .font(.system(size: 18))
    Text(url)
        .bold()
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
}
```

Comment: ok, add this `(alignment: .leading)` to the first VStack.

Comment: Is not a VStack, is a Link()

Comment: I know it's a Link, put my answer inside the Link. Where did you put it, outside the Link?

Answer (score -1):

If you need this texts to be on one line - just put them In a horizontal stack -

```
HStack (alignment: .leading) {
Text(title)
    .bold()
    .font(.system(size: 18))
Text(url)
    .bold()
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
```

}

Comment: This isn't what they were looking for. They were talking about the alignment of the text. `"i want to have 2 Text() view the one below the other"`