# How to left align text in swift UI?

Tags: swift, text, swiftui

I am trying to align left text in Text component in Swift UI.

[image: aling text]

As you can see on above image I applied with below code but does not work. Anything missing?

```
Text(titleSring).frame(alignment: .trailing).background(Color.red)
```

Comment: you are giving align to text... so it is already in center. if you want whole red part(label) in center you need to give Alignment to HStack

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61139506/5941807)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A frame alignment is for entire view (which is square), you need multi-line text alignment, like

```
Text(titleSring)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
```