# Prevent overflow of Element in ZStack SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an arrangement like this for a Horizontal Progress bar in SwiftUI

```
    ZStack {
    // UI Content
    HStack{
    Text("")
    .frame (width:300)
    }
}
```

The problem is text will move outside the ZStack when it is at the extreme right or left.

This is what I am trying to achieve (2nd image)

[image: Problem]

Any solution to achieve this?

Comment: Did you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443535/swiftui-text-alignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this solution using the alignment property. Idk whether this is the correct solution or a workaround.

First I made the Stack that contains the text to take the entire width of its parent.

Since the parent element was made using a ForEach, the text will be only displayed in some indices of List.

and I created a function like this

```
func textAlignment (currentIndex: int, totalIndex:Int) -> Alignment {

if (currentIndex == 0){
return Alignment.leading
}
if (currentIndex == totalIndex-1){
return Alignment.trailing
}
return Alignment.center
}
```

and I added this to Text stack using `.frame(alignment: textAlignment ())` property.